# MS Cognitive Services CreateImagesFromData UnknownMediaType

Tags: c#, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to use the API for uploading training images.
https://southcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/d9a10a4a5f8549599f1ecafc435119fa/operations/58d5835bc8cb231380095be3

Here is my code.

```
public async Task<CreateImageResult> CreateImagesFromData(byte[] _image)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_baseAddress);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Training-key", _trainingKey);

        HttpResponseMessage response;

        using (var content = new ByteArrayContent(_image))
        {
            response = await client.PostAsync(String.Format("Training/projects/{0}/images/image?tagIds=Default", _projectId), content);
        }

        HttpContent data = response.Content;
        string result = await data.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CreateImageResult>(result);
    }
}
```

This request throws me an `UnkonwnMediaType`, and I'm wondering what I'm missing.

The `_image` parameter is an valid `image/jpeg` byte array.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer myself.

```
public async Task<CreateImageResult> CreateImagesFromData(byte[] _image)
{
    HttpContent bytesContent = new ByteArrayContent(_image);

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_baseAddress);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Training-key", _trainingKey);

        HttpResponseMessage response;

        using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
        {
            content.Add(bytesContent, "Image", "Image");
            response = await client.PostAsync(String.Format("Training/projects/{0}/images/image?tagIds=Default", _projectId), content);
        }

        HttpContent data = response.Content;
        string result = await data.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CreateImageResult>(result);
    }
}
```